# regex to extract mandatory words and optional sequence of numbers

Tags: regex

I am trying to use a regex to match a text.
If any word in a list of mandatory words is found identified in group named `code`, but only I need to extract optional sequences of numbers in a group named `phone`.

`blah pin blah 111222333  blah puk blah 12 blah 123456789 blah`

I am expecting to match and find groups names code and number if pin or puk is the next

I am trying something like this

```
(?<code>\b(pin|puk)\b)|(?<phone>\b(\d{9})\b)
```

but if numbers are found it will match even if there are code names in the text.

Thanks

Comment: Is each input a separate line (ie there aren't other inputs one after the other together in the same line)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! To make your question more clear, give some input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a pattern with an alternation `|` and this way there is no "rule" for a relation between the matches.

You could capture pin or puk and then optionally capture 9 digits without crossing another occurrence of pin or puk

```
\b(?<code>pin|puk)\b(?:(?:(?!\b(?:pin|puk)\b).)*?\b(?<phone>\d{9})\b)?
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b(?<code>pin|puk)\b` Group *code* match either `pin` or `puk`
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as whole part

  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

    - `(?!\b(?:pin|puk)\b).` Match a single character if what is directly to the right is not `pin` or `puk`
  - `)*?` Close the non capture group, and repeat as few times as possible
- `\b(?<phone>\d{9})\b` Group *phone* matching 9 digits
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/R9WK4o/1).

Comment: it's almost what I am was expecting, but if two phone numbers are together with no pin|puk in the middle the second one is not captured like for example in "blah pin blah 111222333 blah puk blah 12 blah 123456789 blah 123456789". Thanks

Comment: @ToniRincon You can not dynamically capture groups like that. You could match multiple numbers after it without crossing another pin or puk and then after process that match retrieving the numbers from it. What is the tool or language that you are using?